# Using form to edit a selection on subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a main form with a subform as a datasheet to be used as an asset viewer. I have three buttons that I want to implement in this main form, add/edit/delete entry. The add and edit button will open a new form to add or edit entries in the datasheet. I have the add button working well, however how can I make the edit button edit the row that is selected in the subform (data table)? As it is currently, the edit button will only open with the first entry of that data table. Thanks and hopefully someone out there could help me out.

Comment: To clarify: in MS Access, you have a form that contains a subform onto a related table. You have an edit button, that opens up the first row in the subform for editing. What you want is for the edit button to open the currently selected row, not the first row. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct @RDFozz

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a particular row, you need a button on that row. The way to get that to work is not to use a datasheet but use Format and Default View to create a Continuous Form. Add the required fields and your button to open a new form. Generally, you make that form as short as possible.

When you view the parent form with this subform, it will repeat the rows with data and the button in the row can then be used to open that specific row.